# Northern Ireland and Southern Ireland

Tags: discussion, tags

At present, there is an `ireland` tag, with no guidance at all. Unfortunately, "Ireland" may refer either to a country, or to an island comprising both the country and the province of Northern Ireland. The rational thing to do, considering that the two are jurisdictions separate both from each other and from everywhere else, would be to make clear that the present tag refers only to Southern Ireland, and to create a separate `northern-ireland` tag. However, since there are strong feelings on both sides of the border about the quondam Republic of Ireland's appropriation of the name, reason may not be the only criterion. There are only twenty-five questions using the present tag, some of which refer to the South, some to the North and quite a few unclear; if nobody has considered it important enough to write a tag description, should we let sleeping dogs lie?

Comment: Is the body of law in Southern Ireland significantly different from that which applies in Northern Ireland and the [tag:united-kingdom]?

Comment: @feetwet; They are different countries, so yes;  assuming you consider 'mexico' and 'new-mexico' significantly different. However, they diverged only in 1922 or thereabouts.

Comment: Yeah, hrm. I mean if we can change the tags so that at least one question has each (of whatever tag we end up wanting to call it) then at least it'll exist, but then I think the tags get autocompleted based on what's entered and so people entering Ireland will probably just get the existing tag.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that just "Ireland" on its own would be ambiguous, and can't be reasonably synonymised to one or the other of North Ireland or South Ireland without being arbitrary and creating unnecessary upset.

Therefore, the best course of action is

1. create both tags for the separate jurisdictions, and
2. blacklist the "just-Ireland" tag

Comment: This would be good, but what should the 'South Ireland' tag actually be? It is no longer the Republic of Ireland and, as I noted, many people feel that it is actually 'Ireland'.

Comment: @TimLymington why is it "no longer the Republic of Ireland"?  That's the legal description it refers to itself as in many of its laws and official documents - "Ireland" is also used.  I can't see any recent political changes which have made RoI verboten... Am I missing something?